# Implementation of time series cross-validation

Tags: r, time-series, cross-validation

I am working with time series 551 of the monthly data of the M3 competition.

So, my data is :

```
library(forecast)
library(Mcomp)
# Time Series
# Subset the M3 data to contain the relevant series 
ts.data<- subset(M3, 12)[[551]]
print(ts.data)
```

**I want to implement time series cross-validation for the last 18 observations of the in-sample interval**.

Some people would normally call this “forecast evaluation with a rolling origin” or something similar.

*How can i achieve that ? Whats means the in-sample interval ? Which is the timeseries i must evaluate?*

Im quite confused , any help in order to light up this would be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tsCV` function of the `forecast` package is a good place to start.

From its documentation,

> tsCV(y, forecastfunction, h = 1, window = NULL, xreg = NULL, initial = 0, .
> ..)
>
> Let ‘y’ contain the time series y[1:T]. Then ‘forecastfunction’ is
> applied successively to the time series y[1:t], for t=1,...,T-h,
> making predictions f[t+h]. The errors are given by e[t+h] =
> y[t+h]-f[t+h].

That is first tsCV fit a model to the y[1] and then forecast y[1 + h],  next fit a model to y[1:2] and forecast y[2 + h] and so on for T-h steps.

The tsCV function returns the forecast errors.

Applying this to the training data of the `ts.data`

```
# function to fit a model and forecast
fmodel <- function(x, h){
  forecast(Arima(x, order=c(1,1,1), seasonal = c(0, 0, 2)), h=h)
}
 
# time-series CV
cv_errs <- tsCV(ts.data$x, fmodel, h = 1)

# RMSE of the time-series CV
sqrt(mean(cv_errs^2, na.rm=TRUE))
# [1] 778.7898
```

In your case, it maybe that you are supposed to

1. fit a model to ts.data$x and then forecast ts.data$xx[1]
2. fit mode the c(ts.data$x, ts.data$xx[1]) and forecast(ts.data$xx[2]),
   so on.